# How to check if ManyToMany field is not empty?

Tags: python, django, django-models

How do I check if there are any ManyToMany field objects related to my model object?

For example, I have a model:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    related_categories = models.ManyToManyField('self', blank=True)
```

I want to do something only if there are related objects existing:

```
if example_category.related_categories:
    do_something()
```

I tried to do `example_category.related_categories`, `example_category.related_categories.all()`, `example_category.related_categories.all().exists()`, `example_category.related_categories.count()`, but none of these works for me.

I have no any additional conditions to filter by.

Is there any easy way to check emptiness of this field?

Comment: What is happening if you do that, this looks like the correct solution. Note however that here your `related_categories` is *symmetrical*. So that means if `a` is related to `b`, then `b` is related to `a`.

Comment: `.exists()` would the right solution here.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it looks like my condition is always true, even when there are no related objects. Can the blank argument cause this, maybe?

Comment: @Dibidalidomba: no... `blank` actually has impact on the forms. But as said before, if you add `a` to the `related_categories` of `b`, then this means that the `related_categories` of `a` are non-empty as well.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

you should use the .exists method:

```
related_categories = example_category.related_categories
if related_categories.exists():
    # do something
```